# Page reloading on form submit, console.log messages not showing, CSS not showing

Tags: css, angular, forms, console.log

I am going through and Angular Basics course on Simplilearn.com and am on the Angular Forms lesson. When I hit submit, the page refreshes automatically and nothing shows in the console. Also none of the CSS is showing.

.html file:
[.html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v053X.png)

.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';  

@Component({  
  selector: 'app-form-component',  
  templateUrl: './form-component.component.html',  
  styleUrls: ['./form-component.component.css']  
})  

export class FormComponentComponent{  

  submit(login: any){  
    console.log("form submitted", login);  
  }  
}
```

.css file:

```
div{
  text-align: center;
}

label{
  text-align: left;
}
```

app.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormComponentComponent } from './form-component/form-component.component';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FormComponentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

According to the lesson, the message "form submitted" as well as the form info should be visible in the console without the page reloading. All of the text should be in the middle of the page.

Importing ReactiveFormsModule didn't change anything.

Comment: Please do not post your code as image. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Your code looks like Ok (well, the "input" should not finished with `/>`  else with `>` but it's dosn't important) and, as you say, the page should not refresh. If you're adding the FormsModule after execute `ng serve` try re-execute the `ng serve` again

Comment: @Eliseo Thank you! I was using a VSCode extension to display the code in my browser. Everything started working after executing ng serve.